Past or perfect
Which is better?


Now I need money. I have nothing to sell except the books that my mother has bought me.


Or


Now I need money. I have nothing to sell except the books that my mother bought me.



for me, not to

bought me without a preposition would also work.

In (2), the books could have been bought for you a long time ago. (1) would usually imply that they were bought recently.

You are the best! @ Kate Bunting

(1) Could also mean they were bought over a long period of time, e.g. all the books your mother bought you over your entire lifetime up till now.

You mean permenant in my whole lifetime up till now, for example "I have the books that my mother has bought for me every years."@Stuart F
